# How to check if a database exists without using information_schema or knowing the name of any table in the db?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a setup thing and it would be neat if I could check for the existence of a db on a given host by name (assuming the user and password provided have access to it).

I can't use information_schema because I might not have access rights to it.

I can't try selecting anything from a table because I don't necessarily know the names of the tables in the database.

Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `show databases`. It'll list all databases you have access to.

Or if you want to be more specific: `show databases like "dbname"`.

Also, you *always* have access to information_schema, at least to those records that are related to the databases you have access to.